# Advanced reverse engineering software - including kernel mode debuggers

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, debugging, reverse-engineering

I need an advanced reverse engineering software/tool for Windows environment (32 bit or 64 bit, Windows 8 or Windows 10 etc. - preferably 64 bit Windows 10) including low-level kernel mode debuggers which doesn't require you to have two computers.

Regarding debuggers, I have tried:

- Windbg requires two computers as I know
- Ollydbg is not much advanced as I know
- Any other software like "Syser" after "SoftICE" had been discontinued.

I'd also need disassemblers (after IDA Pro etc.), patching tools (hex etc.) and any other miscellaneous reversing tools or de-compilers etc. Strictly for educational purpose only.

Comment: Gratis? Do you need any other features?

Comment: Are you looking for a single software to cover it all? // I've just edited your question to make it fit this site (we don't do research for what's famous or most-used – we recommend software that fits given requirements). Still, your question looks like you are searching for multiple different tools. If that's so, please [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Also see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: As the [top 2 user in the WinDbg tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windbg/topusers) I don't see an alternative to WinDbg at this time. It is *the* official Microsoft debugger. It does not need 2 computers for kernel debugging. Although it can disassemble, you'll not be happy with it, since IDA Pro is much more powerful. Also, WinDbg does not include a patching system. What you need is a complete tool chain which may consist of dozens of programs, since you'll need special tools for .NET (SOS, SOSex, dotPeek) and other languages. Your request is too broad for this site as it stands now.

Comment: You might have a look on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ for tools these guys are using. However, they don't really like beginners over there. A question like this may easily be downvoted. Looking at the [tags](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tags), IDA is possibly the most favorite tool for reverse engineering. Combine that with WinDbg for kernel debugging and you can already get very far I'd say.